# Proving faces of polyhedron

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

let $F(k)$ be the number of faces of a convex polyhedron with k edges

how can we prove that $F(k) > 1$ for some $k$?

I know Euler's Formula for Polyhedra: $V-E+F=2$, and $\sum k\,F(k) = 2E$.

this means that some pair of faces has same number of edges for any polyhedron

here is restatement through dual: i want to prove that there is a pair of vertex with same number of edges.

Comment: if someone knows how to make nice format please show me. thanks

Comment: I don't understand. A cube has $12$ edges and $6$ faces, so $F(12)=6>1$. Have I misinterpreted your question?

Comment: cube has 6 faces with 4 edges each, so $F(4) = 6$. I want to prove that there are faces with same amount of edges no matter polyhedron. cube is example of place where theorem works, i think theorem always hold. (also thank you to people who fixed formatting :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose not. Each face has a distinct number of edges.

Consider the face with the most number of edges, say $k$.

On each edge, there must be at least 1 distinct face, with at most $k-1$ edges.

We have $k$ faces, each has a distinct number of edges from 0 to $k-1$.

This is absurd. Hence contradiction.

Comment: beautiful proof. i was overcomplicate.. thank very much for solution. :)